# How to show page numbering after a specific page

Tags: page-numbering, fancyhdr

I'd like to show page numbering after table of contents, but Latex starts showing page numbering on list of figures

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english,portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{textcomp,gensymb}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{authblk}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhf{}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}

\setstretch{1}
\listoffigures*
\listoftables*

\chapter*{Lista de Abreviaturas e Siglas}
\setstretch{1}
\input{Chapters/Abbreviations.tex}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introdução}
\setstretch{1.5}
\input{Chapters/Chapter1.tex}
```

Comment: Try writing first `\pagestyle{empty}`,  then `pagestyle{plain}` just before the first chapter after the table of contents.

Comment: It doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

You're working with the `fancyhdr` package, with a setup that is designed to show the page number in the upper-right-hand corner of each page.

Immediately after `\begin{document}` you need to issue the instruction

```
\pagenumbering{gobble}
```

to, well, "gobble up" the page numbers before they get printed. Then, on the first "real" page, issue the instructions

```
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\addtocounter{page}{<n>}
```

where `<n>` is the number of pages in the document's front matter. (In your basic example, that number is `4`.)

A full example -- observe that I had to comment out the `\input` directives since I don't have access to the underlying tex files:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % do you really need 'T2A' as well?
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,
            bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english,portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{textcomp,gensymb}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{setspace}  % this was missing

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhf{}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}

\begin{document} % this was missing

\pagenumbering{gobble}  % new

%%\setstretch{1} % not needed, as "1" is the default
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\chapter*{Lista de Abreviaturas e Siglas}
%%\input{Chapters/Abbreviations.tex} % commented out deliberately
\tableofcontents

\clearpage             %new
\pagenumbering{arabic} % new
\addtocounter{page}{4} % new
\setstretch{1.5}

\chapter{Introdução}

%%\input{Chapters/Chapter1.tex} % commented out deliberately
\end{document} % this was missing
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thanks!